# Static Method on object inheriting Disposable

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, garbage-collection

I've recently inherited an asp.net project that is running into memory leaks. In my investigation I noticed there are a lot of custom classes implementing IDisposable, but they aren't employing "using" when called. I've been fixing these issues, but one use case I was curious about was putting static methods on the class. Something like this:

```
public class ImDisposable : IDisposable{
   public static GetList(string search){
       //doStuff
   }
   //implement IDisposable
}

public class UseDisposable{
   public void GetList(string search){
      var list = ImDisposable.GetList(search);
      //do stuff
   }
}
```

I've never seen anything like this done, and I was curious how the GC handles this scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods don't rely on any particular instance, and therefore they shouldn't be able to access instance members of your class which might tie up un-managed resources.

You need not consider them when thinking about Disposing of resources

---

On a related note, The existence of methods has little to do with IDisposable either.  It doesn't dispose of the "methods" per-se, It disposes of unmanaged resources that an instance of the class might use.  (such as open file streams)

Answer (score 1):

You may be confusing memory leaks and garbage collection... just because you're not calling `Dispose()` doesn't mean you'll have a leak.  You get a leak when:

**(1)** The class you didn't dispose has a handle to unmanaged resources, e.g. a file stream.  Theoretically, if a class implements IDisposable, it has unmanaged resources, but I've seen enough empty dispose methods that I'm jaded.  I.E. for static classes/members, unless you have a static variable that needs disposed, that's not your memory leak.

Also, static members would only ever have one instance, regardless of how many classes you instantiate, and you can't really have a leak when no new instances are ever created.

**(2)**  You keep object references when you don't need/mean to... good example would be event listeners, especially those connected as a lambda.  Not calling Dispose() on a database connection is also considered a leak, even though Dispose() simply returns the connection to the connection pool.

Also keep in mind that a growing memory footprint is not necessarily a leak.  Garbage Collection is only performed when the .NET runtime deems it necessary... if there's still plenty of memory available, there's no need to GC.

Highly simplified overview; I'm mostly saying that nothing `static` is related to your memory leak.  There's a good article on pinning down memory leaks [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42721/Best-Practices-No-Detecting-NET-application-memo)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague.

You may see the book CLR via C# by Richter for explanation about the garbage collection.  Though my feeling is that your question is more about the interaction between a static method in a non-static class and the garbage collector.  The above aforementioned book covers that too.
In general, a static method that allocates a resource will behave in a similar manor to a non-static method that allocates resources.  However, the IDisposable interface will operate on the instance of the class.  Therefore, your
    static GetList(..)
method should not use resources that need the IDisposable implementation to free.